# Find a convex polygon $P$ s.t. $P\subset Q \subset (1+\epsilon) P $.

Tags: euclidean-geometry, convex-geometry, metric-geometry

Problem : Assume that $Q$ is a compact convex plane figure containing $R$-ball of the center origin. Then prove that for any $\epsilon >0$, there is a convex polygon $P\subset Q$ s.t. $$ P\subset Q\subset 
(1+\epsilon)\cdot P $$

**Proof :** Define $A = \bigg\{ \delta (x,y) \bigg| x,\ y\in \mathbb{Z}\bigg\}$ From this the book says that $\epsilon = \frac{10\ {\rm diam}\ Q}{R}\delta,\ \delta < 
\frac{R}{10}$

> **Question** : How can we obtain this ?

The following is my different approach :

(1) $x_i$ is point in $\partial Q$ s.t. $|x_i-x_{i+1} |
\leq R$

Then ${\rm conv}\ \{x_i\}$ contains $\frac{R}{2}$-ball.

(2) Redefine $x_i\in \partial Q$ s.t. the arc
$\widetilde{x_ix_{i+1}}$ in $\partial Q$ has a
length $\leq M=\min\ \{\ R\epsilon , R\ \} \ (\ast)$.

If
$$|o-x_i|,\ |o-x_{i+1}|\geq \frac{R}{2},$$
then consider a line containing $[x_ix_{i+1}]$ and a line containing $
(1+\epsilon )\cdot [x_i x_{i+1}]$.

Note that the distance between two lines is greater than
$\frac{R}{2} \epsilon$.

From $\ast$ the arc $\widetilde{x_ix_{i+1}}$ is between two triangles $ox_ix_{i+1},\ o(1+\epsilon )x_i(1+\epsilon)x_{i+1}$.

Hence we have the desired $P ={\rm conv}\ \{x_i\}$.

> Here in $\ast$ we do not have diameter term.

Reference : From Euclid to Alexandrov; a guided tour - Petrunin and Yashinski.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $\varepsilon$. Define $A = \{ (m,n)\delta |m,\ n\in
\mathbb{Z}\}$ We let $\delta = \frac{R}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{1}{M}$ for
large positive integer $M$.

Then the convex polygon $C = {\rm conv} (A\cap Q)$ contains
$\frac{R}{2}$-ball whose center is origin $o$.

For $x\in \partial
Q$, let $y\in [xo] $ s.t. $$ |x-y|=d< \frac{R}{2} \varepsilon$$

Further there is $r>0$ s.t. a closed ball $B[r,y]$ is in $C$. Here
$r$ is independent of $x,\ y$.

If $M$ is large, then each $B[r,y]$ contains at least nine squares
generated from $A$.

Here we can assume that *a square placed in
center contains a point $y$*. Hence $C$ contains $y$.

If $C\cap
[ox]=[oz]$ where $z$ is a point in a line segment $[ox]$, then
\begin{align*}
|oz| (1+ \varepsilon )&\geq |oz| +
\frac{R}{2}\varepsilon
\\&\geq |oz| +d \\&\geq
|ox|
\end{align*}  which finishes the proof.